# A Top. Space $X$ is compact if $\exists$ basis $B$ for $X$ such that every open cover of $X$ ...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> A Top. Space $X$ is compact if $\exists$ basis $B$ for $X$ such that
>   every open cover of $X$ which consists of elements of this basis has a
>   finite subcover.

I think this problem seems obvious but I still want to make sure what do you guys think about this problem? It looks just like the definition of compactness?

Comment: The usual definition is $X$ is compact if for any open cover of $X$, there exists a finite subcover. Can you turn any open cover of $X$ into an open cover of $X$ consisting of basis elements (probably going to have to be a subcover)?

Comment: Are you sure it's »$\exists$ basis ...« and not »$\forall$ bases ...«?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: In this case both quantifiers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the whole topology is a base of itself, one direction follows from the definition, for the other direction, you have to prove that any open cover $(U_i)$ has a finite subcover - knowing it only for open covers $(V_j)$ with $\{V_j: j \in J\} \subseteq B$.

Comment: So, we must find an open subcover consisting only of the elements $V_j$ that are in $B$? I am stuck which this finite subcollection we can choose... Can you help me? thanks. @Martini

Comment: **Hint**: Given any open cover $(U_i)$, consider $\mathcal C := \{V \in B \mid \exists i\, U_i \subseteq V\}$. Show that this is an open cover. By assumption, $\mathcal C$ has a finite subcover $\mathcal C'$ for $V \in \mathcal C'$ choose an $i_V\in I$ with $V \subseteq U_{i_V}$. Then $(U_{i_V})_{V \in \mathcal C'}$ is a finite subcover. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the definition of compactness which is :

> A topological space $X$ is said to be compact if for every open cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $X$, there is a finite subset $J \subseteq I$ such that $(U_j)_{j\in J}$ is again a cover of $X$.

Here, $X$ satifies the property a priori **only** for open cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ with $U_i \in B$ for all $i \in I$.

**Hint** : show that every open cover $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ of $X$ yields an open cover $(U'_j)_{j\in I'}$ with the $U'_j \in B$.